# Activating the Camera RAW plugin of Adobe Bridge CC (free) by buying Photoshop Elements - anybody who has tried it?

Tags: adobe-camera-raw, photoshop-elements, adobe-bridge

Adobe bridge CC (which is free) enables its support for the Adobe Camera Raw plug-in when Photoshop CC (trial) is activated too. The Bridge+ARC combo satisfies my need for quick adjustments and media browsing, but it won't run without an activated version of Photoshop.

I was wondering if the following *trick* will work:
If I buy Photoshop Elements 15 (which at times can be found on the cheap) and install it alongside Bridge CC; will the Camera RAW plug-in be re-enabled inside Bridge CC or will it only work from within PSE?

Of course I've read that Camera RAW for PSE disables things like gradient filters, split toning and spot removal, but I don't mind; If I need more fine-editing I can always open the raw inside Affinity Photo that is more capable.

Anybody who thinks/knows this will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## In short

> One can utilize the **Adobe Camera Raw**(ACR) bundled with **Photoshop
>   Elements**(PSE),as if it were near-native to **Bridge Creative Cloud**(CC)
>   (read below for the caveats though, because *there are some quirks and some things you cannot do*)

## What works and what doesn't

- The **Adobe Camera Raw** included with **PSE** seems to be a separate instance from the **CC** one (probably resides in a different folder too)
- From within the **PSE Editor**, opening a RAW file will bring you the **ACR** dialog (simplified for **PSE**, without the advanced tools that come with the full **CC** version - complete list [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/camera-raw-differences-photoshop-photoshop.html))
- From withing **Bridge CC**, clicking on *Open in Camera Raw...* shows the message `Camera Raw editing is not enabled`. However,
- from within **Bridge** if you press on *Open With -> Adobe Photoshop Elements 15 Editor*, it will in fact launch **ACR** (PSE's version; **after** initializing **PSE**), at which point

  - you have the opportunity to work on the RAW just as before, and either
  - press Done (or Cancel) and return to **Bridge**, or
  - press Open Image and have the image open further in **PSE**.

### What Works

- **Bridge** can without any issue send multiple files to PSE's ACR (which helps a bit with batch editing)
- **Bridge** seems to be reading the new/updated XMP files just fine as if they were "its own"

  - the previews generated are accurate
  - there is also the icon indicating that this particular raw file, has  adjustments applied on it
  - the edited thumbnails inside **Bridge** refresh instantly as if they were made with its own version of **ACR** (ie the full **CC ACR**)
- inside **ACR**

  - you can re-edit adjustments that were previously created by the full **CC ACR** version and
    interestingly enough
  - the adjustments that are not supported here (like spots removed, perspective correction etc) will remain, albeit no further adjustable. However
  - if you click *reset camera raw defaults*, these adjustments will be discarded as well.

### What doesn't Work

#### major caveats

- you can no longer use the *Develop Settings* -> *Camera Raw Defaults*/*Previous Conversion*/*Clear Settings* from within **Bridge**, so you have to do it from within **ACR** which means that for batch editing, there are a few extra steps involved.
- you loose access to good tools such as *the spot removal tool*, *split toning*, *perspective correction*, *lens correction*, *dehaze* and of course *masks* (complete list [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/camera-raw-differences-photoshop-photoshop.html))

#### minor caveats

- you may end up keeping a copy of **PSE** *always open* since it needs to have been launched before **ACR** launches (unlike the **CC** version that can be hosted directly by **Bridge**)

  - another implication of that is, that if inside **ACR** you click *Done* or *Cancel*, the **ACR** window will close, but *not* the **PSE Editor** window
- The *Open in Camera Raw...* context menu (just like the *Develop Settings* mentioned above) inside **Bridge** doesn't do anything useful anymore - instead you have to click on *Open With* -> *Adobe Photoshop Elements 15 Editor* which is a bit more cumbersome thanks to the one extra click, and having to scan for it in a bigger list (if you have multiple photo-editing applications installed).
- Being an independant version of **ACR**, also means that you probably are not eligible for perpetual updates, unlike the **CC** version that updates forever. This is just an assumption, but the compatibility list [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/kb/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html) indicates that **PSE** version (PSE 13) never made it to ACR 9.0 or above)
- after editing in Camera RAW, if instead of closing the window, you decide to press Open in order to edit the image inside **PSE**, **PSE** apparently imposes further constraints, when compared to editing the same files inside **PS**. Among others, you are limited to 8bit per channel.

### Conclusion

All in all, it's quite usable even though not directly supported.

## Background (how I tested it)

on my system I have **Bridge CC 2017** and **Photoshop CC 2017** trial, but the **Photoshop** trial has already expired. Since then, whenever I would choose from within **Bridge** the *Open in Camera Raw...* option, I'd get an error message (`Camera Raw editing is not enabled. Camera Raw editing required that a qualifying product has been launched at least once to enable this feature.`).

1. After downloading, installing and launching **ACR** from within **PSE 15**'s trial version, I tested **Bridge** again but no luck. The **PSE** trial that I downloaded had **ACR 9.7** (or was it 9.6?).
2. From within the program I was given the option to download a newer version of **PSE** and a newer **ACR** version (9.8), which happens to be the same version that my **Bridge CC 2017** contains; so I thought I could try that too. This hinted that **CC** and **PSE** had their own separate copy of **ACR** that needs separate updating.
3. I installed the update, but no luck with getting **Bridge** to integrate properly with that version either.

### afterthoughts

I haven't tried the full version of **Photoshop Elements**, only the trial and I haven't uninstalled the expired trial of **Photoshop CC 2017** but I don't see why this could had any different result.

---

copied and edited from my reply found on the adobe support forum [here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9275680#9275680)

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! There's one more point that maybe worths to be added: as you develop a photo in ACR everything happens in 16 bits, but when click "Open" to do more edits in PSE you may be prompted to convert the image to 8 bits, since PSE doesn't fully support 16 bits editing. For example, you can crop, adjust levels and curves and still save your photo in 16 bits, but you can't use layers or use the clone tool without converting it to 8 bits.

Comment: Thank you @gerlos - good point! I added it - While I avoided touching the topic of opening the file inside PSE (or even PS) understandably at some point you need to at least export your images and you'll have to use either PS, PSE or a 3rd party image editing software.